# navigation drawer crush when cart fragment bottom navigation invisible and backpress use bottom navigation visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    public static Toolbar toolbar;
    public static BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,R.id.cartFragment,R.id.wishFragment,R.id.dashboardFragment)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

    }
    

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Cart Fragment in bottom navigation

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);

        HomeActivity main = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
//You can access all public variable and methods of MainActivity.
//simply call
        main.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        main.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return view;
    }

}
```

- In Cat fragment first botttom navigation invisible
- when backpress from the cart fragment at that time use bottom navigation visible. because of, without visible bottom navigation backpress in MainActivity bottom navigation didn't show.
  ***When back from the card fragment and click navigation drawer app crush

Comment: What is your Cart Fragment even trying to do? If you want to hide and show your bottom nav on a particular destination, there's [already an API for that](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events).

Comment: @ianganniballake thank you,  but when backpress from fragment and then click navigation drawer..my application crushed